# python qpageview - how to draw a rectangle

Tags: python, qt

I am trying to use [qpageview](https://qpageview.org/index.html) library, but the documentation is quite limited and the core developer does not answer any question. This library is intended to make easier the creation of a PDF editor based on Qt and Poppler.

I am able to import a PDF and I am able to display a slection box with the following code:

```py
import qpageview
from qpageview.export import pdf
from qpageview.rubberband import Rubberband

from PyQt5.Qt import *
a = QApplication([])

v = qpageview.View()
v.show()
v.loadPdf("../pdf/Frances_01.pdf")
r = Rubberband()
v.setRubberband(r)
```

What I would like to do is to draw white rectangle on the selection made with the Rubberband. It is easy to get the selection: `r.selection()`. But I don't know how to draw on the existing pages.

Any help would be welcomed.